# Create a volume group from a logical volume instead of a physical volume

Tags: lvm

Is it possible to create a volume group from a logical volume instead of a physical volume? If so, are there any pitfalls in doing so?

Use case:

Installing OpenStack Compute on a a system that already has all of the physical volumes assigned to a singe volume group. The nova-volume service requires a separate volume group, [as described in the documentation](http://docs.openstack.org/diablo/openstack-compute/admin/content/managing-volumes.html). I want to know if I can carve off a logical volume and then create the "nova-volumes" volume group.

Comment: I don't know for sure that you can't create a PV from a LV and make a VG containing that PV, but it sounds like a maintenance nightmare. I strongly suggest that you carve off a *PV* and put it in its own VG called `nova-volumes`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it *is* possible, though you are adding complexity.
I would use this approach either experimentally or as a last resort, only after you have explored other solutions.

paraphrasing `man pvcreate` "pvcreate initializes PV for later use by the LVM. Each PV can be a ... or *meta device* ...

Apparently an LV qualifies as a *meta device*.

Empirically speaking, the following worked just fine

```
pvcreate /dev/sda16
vgcreate demo /dev/sda16
lvcreate --name lv -l '100%VG' demo
pvcreate /dev/mapper/demo-lv  
vgcreate wrappervg /dev/mapper/demo-lv  
lvcreate --name lv -l '100%VG' wrappervg  
mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/wrappervg-lv  
mkdir /mnt/wrapper  
mount /dev/mapper/wrappervg-lv /mnt/wrapper  
touch /mnt/wrapper/foo
```

Comment: Added the use case description.

Comment: Guess you could do it this was, but I would reconfigure the vg to use less space, (backup/restore), then create nova-volume vg/lv separate instead of layered. Regardless, it will work. I don't know where issues might arise, say with snapshots.

Comment: @bdowning Is it really possible? I thought only supported block devices could be LVM physical volumes, not including LVM logical volumes.

Comment: Empirically speaking, it works. As I said I would not pursue this path except either experimentally or as a last resort. I have no idea what implications this config holds. Try it, it does work.

Comment: @bdowning Ok, thanks. I fully agree that I'd only do this as a last resort, it sounds high-maintenance.

Comment: Just a remark: In order to "play" with PVs I use loopback-devices, that are made out of files on mounted LVs. Even that is possible.

Comment: Separate volume group (instead of one inside a logical volume) has same drawbacks than using physical disk partitions: resizing is complicated and somewhat risky. I do understand the critical attitude on this one. That's why I am also trying to find some facts about this.

Volume group on top of logical volume does create some extra complexity, but as far as I can see, I personally could live with the level of that. However, I'd like to know if there are some other practical reasons why it might not be a recommended way to go.

Comment: I don't agree that resizing is complicated or risky, assuming one has a current backup handy. Occam's razor is the principle I admin by, adding no more complexity than necessary. If one *must* configure a nested VG/LV, then there should be a good reason to do so (use case).
In my experience I've found the greatest risk to data usually comes from human error, again: backup!